# Creating compressed gzip file python 3

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html creating a compressed gzip file requires the following:

```
import gzip
content = b"Lots of content here"
with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error using python 3 `AttributeError: module 'gzip' has no attribute 'open'`

not sure what is happening....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've called something else `gzip.py`, which is shadowing the standard library module. Rename it and any compiled files.